# SQL Ordering of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column of strings which i am trying to get in the order currently shown below.

I have tried substrings, case statements and using the Right syntax to try and achieve the proper ascending order but i cannot figure it  out.

The string will never exceed a length of 4, e.g A10a is as large as it can get and it always follows this format (string, number, string)

```
A1,
A2,
A2a,
A2b,
...,
...,
...,
A10,
A10a
```

I was trying to perhaps extract the last character and if its a letter then convert it to a number using a case statement, anybody know if this would work?

Is it possible? Any help here appreciated

Comment: It depends on how your field values may vary

Comment: show a proper data sample

Comment: Your data is not stored how you need it. The string `'A10'` comes before the string `'A2'`. Get your data in the form that you need.

Comment: The values you're showing aren't sorted alphanumerically.  It sounds like you want to divide the values into their components, sort on the components, then re-combine the values.

Comment: Is it always letter, digits, letters?

Comment: @Jarlh Yes it is always in this form. At most the data will have a character length of 4 e.g A10a, it cant get longer than this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server+natural-sort

Comment: imo, you need to 'normalize' that column to be able to order by it in the way that you want.

Comment: @Smithy, rather than post useful information in comments. i.e .about the format of the column. Please add it to the question. That way new people can see it immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really ugly, but works:

```
declare @test table (test varchar(4))


insert into @test values ('A1')
insert into @test values ('A2')
insert into @test values ('A2a')
insert into @test values ('A2b')
insert into @test values ('A10')
insert into @test values ('A10a')
insert into @test values ('A10b')

select * ,
 LEFT(test,1), 
 CAST(CASE 
 WHEN LEN(test) =3 AND right(test,1) like '[a-z]' THEN substring(test,2,1)
ELSE substring(test,2,2)
END AS INTEGER)
,CASE WHEN right(test,1) like '[a-z]' THEN RIGHT(test,1) ELSE '' END    

from @test
ORDER BY 
 LEFT(test,1), 
 CAST(CASE 
 WHEN LEN(test) =3 AND right(test,1) like '[a-z]' THEN substring(test,2,1)
ELSE substring(test,2,2)
END AS INTEGER)
,CASE WHEN right(test,1) like '[a-z]' THEN RIGHT(test,1) ELSE '' END
```